# DDD: Choosing aggregate root

Tags: domain-driven-design, aggregate

In my case I have two main concepts: User (main citizen of the system) and Group.
Group has two sub-collections: ranks and roles. Without a group, ranks and roles have no meaning.
When User is assigned to the Group, we also have to pick 1 Role and 1 Rank and assign them to this relationship between User and the Group.

[Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hqrsg.jpg)

Question:

How much aggregate roots do I have here? From the user side its obviously a user (main concept of the system), but what about its relationship with group? AFAIK its forbidden by rules of DDD to reference entities outside of aggregate root.

Answer (score 0):

> AFAIK its forbidden by rules of DDD to reference entities outside of aggregate root.

Well, I would't say it's "forbidden by rules of DDD"... Some times you have no choice. I have to consider the size of the "entities' collection" associated  to the Root's Aggregate. Sometime you can maintain the association in the same aggregation and use some kind of "lazy load" to avoid resource consumption. The Vernon's iDDD book[1] has some advises and use cases around this specific case. Take a look on his blog post[2]

[1] https://www.amazon.com.br/Implementing-Domain-Driven-Design-Vaughn-Vernon/dp/0321834577
[2] https://vaughnvernon.co/?p=838

Comment: Or one can use eventual consistency

Answer (score 0):

You have at least the following options, depending on your business requirements regarding consistency:

1. You have 5 aggregate roots: User, Group, Rank, Role and UserAssignment. The last one must protect the invariant "we also have to pick 1 Role and 1 Rank". For lifetime management you  use eventual consistency between ARs. For example, when you delete a Group you must delete also the orphan Ranks, Roles and UserAssignments.
2. You have User (with UserAssignment as nested entity) and Group (with Role and Rank as nested entities). You have strong consistency inside ARs (when you delete a user all its asignments are also deleted) and eventual consistency between User and Group.

What should you use? Only you could decide. For example, if you choose the first option and delete a user then there could be a delay of seconds/minutes/hours before its assignments are also deleted.

Strong consystency should be used to protect only *real* business invariants because it is not cheap.

P.S. if you need to hold a reference to a nested entity from another AR then you should reconsider your aggregate roots boundaries because your design is most probable wrong.

Comment: Basically both roles and ranks have no meaning without its parent group. Its like:
"Hello, I am the king [role]." "A king of what [group]?". "Of NullPointerException". The application itself is very user-centric, everything evolves around the concept of a user. In your second option, it happens that we have 2 aggregates - user and group, correct? But the user assignment (nested entity in user entity) references nested entities in the group aggregate. Is it what you meant or I didnt understand you?

Comment: Then use a combination of option 1 and 2. I also tried to make you understand how to think in designing aggregates: consistency boundary. There is no absolute answer.

Comment: We can discuss as much as you need in order to understand but no one can tell you exactly what to do

Comment: My current solution: implement 5 aggregate roots: User, Group, Rank, Role and UserAssignment. Role and rank have a relationship to its parent group, because user will often want to follow that relationship in that particular order (a king[role] of foobar[group]), also the app is READ-heavy. Next, we only make a GroupService and push all invariants there (ex: there can only be 1 king in group - createRoleForGroup(group, role)->loadKingRoleForGroup(groupId)->found nothing->save(role)).

Comment: This approach also allows me to make custom specifications for our roles (like get all kings) and thus optimise queries. I separate writes (they go through the group, thus protecting invariants) and reads (just want information). If I want to delete a group - I first check for active UserAssignments, and if they are present - halt execution (user is being event-sourced, we have to unassign users first). If not - delete its child aggregates and itself. Is this approach valid?

Comment: It does not seem right. Business invariants in service is wrong: anemic domain model. Also, in order to protect the invariants UserAssignment should go inside Group.

Comment: Use CQRS if you need query optimisation, do not mix concepts otherwise your model will become anemic or god-like, both being wrong

Comment: What about a situation where there are a lot (and I mean A LOT) of roles in a group and we want to add a king role (and there can only be 1) we will basically have to load an entire collection of roles to a group, to check if there is a king role or not. Unless, of course, we ask the DB directly to check if there are any roles associated with that group that has a seniority of a king, so if its required to move that logic inside the division entity, we will have to also include a role repository inside of group aggregate. Is it ok to do so?

Comment: If there are a lot then you can use the Reservation pattern with a Process manager to manage this situation. Here is a link to read more about this pattern http://www.drdobbs.com/windows/soa-patterns-reservation/228701670

Comment: The problem with querying the db is that there is a situation where the db says that the king role is free but by the time the aggregate is persisted the role is taken by another command execution: clasic concurrency problem

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to change some of the words and we'll see if it helps (hypothetical):

> I have an `Order` and a `Product`.  When I add a `Product` to an `Order` I have to choose a `Store` and a `Colour`.

How would you model this?

`Colour` may very well be a Value Object but `Store` is not.  I would opt for an `OrderItem` Value Object which contains a `Colour` Value Object and a `StoreId` value to capture the relationship.  An `Order` would contain a list of `OrderItem` entries.

Removing `Colour` entries is fine since we have denormalized that bit into the `OrderItem`.  We *could* have another Value Object represent the `Store` but typically we would not delete the store or have some processing to handle a deletion or, even more typical, use referential integrity constraints to prevent deleting a used `Store`.

If you consider ever deleting the `Order` only the `OrderItem` association is also deleted.

In your case `User` and `Group` are probably Aggregate Roots and I'd add a `UserGroup` (or `UserAssignment` as Constantin used).  The `UserGroup` contains the association and related bits.  You would have to identify the real domain structure though.